# Better data structure for multiple checks for a variable than if statements?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, data-structures

So, I have this block of code, and yes it looks ugly. Is there a better a data structure I can use to compare row.add,row.modify,row.delete and row.query with "Y" and call the get_role function? Note this block of code runs in a loop, hence the 'row'.

```
    if row.add == "y"
      role_ids << get_role("c")  
    end
    if row.modify == "y"
      role_ids << get_role("u")
    end
    if row.delete == "y"
      role_ids << get_role("d")
    end
    if row.query == "y"
      role_ids << get_role("r")
    end
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
operations = { :add => "c", :modify => "u", :delete => "d", :query => "r" }
operations.each do |key,value|
  role_ids << get_role(value) if row.send(key) == "y"
end
```

Comment: When you call `row.send(:method_name)`, it's the same as calling `row.method_name`. It's necessary because your operations / method names are stored in an array (because they need corresponding values). For example, `object.delete` and `object.send(:delete)` are identical. Does that help explain?

Comment: Yes I figured , thats why I deleted the comment. Thanks !

Comment: This technique is called *Dynamic Dispatch*.

Comment: Just a small remark: prior to 1.9, Ruby's Hash wasn't ordered, so there's no guarantee that `each` here would traverse the hash in the same order it was defined. If the order is important, one should use array of arrays (pairs) instead of a hash, with no change to the `each` call needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
role_ids << case
  when row.add    == "y" then get_role("c")
  when row.modify == "y" then get_role("u")
  when row.delete == "y" then get_role("d")
  when row.query  == "y" then get_role("r")
end
```

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE !

changed to

```
operations = [row.add,row.modify,row.delete,row.query]
crud=["c","u","d","r"]
operations.each_with_index{|operation,i| if operation == "y" then role_ids << get_role(crud[i]) end}
```

Comment: that will always trigger `get_role("y")`. right track, but not quite.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up Jeriko. I think now the changed version will work.

Comment: This solution is really unreadable. It also introduces additional variables with the cost of more objects to be created.